# React: Provide URL that returns dynamic file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest

I'm creating a ReactJS system that has a rest back-end, using openapi-generator to create an API interface inside our React code in order for the front end to access the Rest Endpoints.

I need to have a URL on our front end that downloads a file. To be clear, this is not a URL that provides a download button, or even a URL that loads a component and auto-downloads a file, but just a URL that directly provides the file and nothing else.

The reason for this is that we provide the ability for our users to create their own custom HTML pages, and in those pages, link to files. The file URL has to work correctly, so they can put custom  tags into the HTML, and have actual images displayed.

I don't want to use the Rest Endpoint URL directly, as that seems bad from a security point of view. What I really need is the following:

1. React component is loaded from URL localhost:1234/file/filename.jpg
2. React component uses API to fetch file based on name
3. React component returns file

The problem is step 3 above, as React Components seem to only want to return html. When I tried to return a basic string, I got the following error message:

```
Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>'.

  Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.

    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.  TS2322
```

I am not sure how to set up a URL in React that is not a component to do this.

I have also tried things like window.URL.createObjectURL, passing in the blob after it is fetched, but the URL generated there is a long UUID sort of URL, and it would be pretty ugly to force the users to use that URL when typing their HTML.

TLDR: I have files in our back end that are dynamic, and I want a ReactJS URL such as localhost:1234/file/filename.jpg that directly returns the file, and nothing else.